# Where is the 3 days difference?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, ubuntu-18.04

I need to get difference between 2 days, not big deal. But when i go from eg: diff days between 2019-06-27 11:00 and 2019-06-30 08:00 (3 days diff) it return 4 days. Every difference > 2 is jumping the 3rd day and returning 1 extra day.

I'm working with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and tried on current last version of Google Chrome Versión 75.0.3770.100 (Build oficial) (64 bits)
I tried momentjs with same problem, then moved to Date object native of javascript and the same problem.

```
var oneDay=24*60*60*1000;
var firstDay= new Date(pickUpDate[2],pickUpDate[1]-1,pickUpDate[0],0,0,0);
var secondDay= new Date(returnDate[2],returnDate[1]-1,returnDate[0],0,0,0);
days=(secondDay.getTime()-firstDay.getTime())/oneDay;
console.log(days)

//input:pickUpDate[]=["01","07","2019"]
//returnDate[]=["03","07","2019"]
//output: 2
//input:pickUpDate[]=["01","07","2019"]
//returnDate[]=["04","07","2019"]
//output: 4


Date1= moment(pickUpDate+' '+phour,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
Date2=moment(returnDate+' '+rhour,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
days=moment.duration(Date2.diff(Date1))/(1000*60*60*24);
console.log(days)

//input:pickUpDate="01/07/2019"
//returnDate="03/07/2019"
//phour="11:00"
//rhour="08:00"
//output: 2.rightdecimals
//input:pickUpDate="01/07/2019"
//returnDate="04/07/2019"
//phour="11:00"
//rhour="08:00"
//output: 4.rightdecimals

//Also tried moment.duration().asDays() and the same history.
```

No errors on the console

**EDIT**

Tried same code at Windows 10 and latest Chorme and is working perfectly, hope somebody have some idea what's going on. My day time is (UTC-06:00) Guadalajara, Ciudad de México, Monterrey

Comment: Are you *sure* these are the inputs you are passing?  I ran your exact code examples and got `3` when using the `Date` object and `2.875` when using Moment (both with the second set of inputs).

Comment: Not your problem, but days are not all 24 hours long where daylight saving is observed, see [*How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: So, how can i avoid this daylight saving problems. I'm at México, tried same code on windows and it's working perfectly. Any idea?